# Postgres on local machine: rake db:migrate produces an error

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I am adding an application to a new OSX machine (10.9.3 with RVM and Ruby 2.1.1). I am using postgresapp, like in the rest of my work environments, but here I am getting an error when I try to migrate the database.

I performed `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create` (which creates the databases properly) prior to migrating.

I can't get even the first migration to go through, always getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "templates" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"templates"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"templates"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/andreimoment/f3a815099b5e3834338e#file-stacktrace

Here's the first migration:

```
class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
      t.string :status
      t.integer :default_page_id
      t.belongs_to :template
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: myuser
  password:
```

myuser has superuser, create db, create role privileges in postgresql

I also created a new rails app with database=postgresql and its migrations work OK.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: I commented out the FactoryGirl gems, ran bundle update and the migrations went through.

What could be the reason for this? Would the FactoryGirl gems try to initialize the records and possibly lead to the condition suggested by Mu?

Comment: That SQL is what ActiveRecord uses to figure out the structure of the `Template` model class (or equivalently, the `templates` database table). So something in your initialization is loading `app/models/template.rb` before the corresponding table exists.

Comment: I commented out the FactoryGirl gems, ran bundle update and the migrations went through.

Comment: do you have factory-girl in your development-group in the Gemfile?

Comment: phoet, I did, but I moved it to the test group and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I'm using factory girl in both developement and test envs. I can't reset my db with rake db:schema:load after droping and recreating database.

**I can confirm that remove FactoriGirl from developement group solve this issue**